# Defining a predicate; need prop=>bool

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to define a function that takes a set and a relation and returns a bool telling if the relation is reflexive on the set.  I tried to define it like this:

```
definition refl::"'a set⇒('a×'a) set⇒bool" where
"refl A R = (∀x. x∈A⟹(x,x)∈R)"
```

but Isabelle gives me the following error:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "prop" and "bool"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  (=) (refl A R) :: bool ⇒ bool
Operand:   ∀x. x ∈ A ⟹ (x, x) ∈ R :: prop
```

I can't seem to find any function to force a "prop" into a "bool".  I also tried changing the definition to set the RHS = True, but I get the same error.
What is the correct way to define my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't go from `prop` to `bool`. But you don't have to: just use the object level connectives (`⟶` and `∀`) instead of the meta-logical ones (`⟹` and `⋀`). They are logically equivalent, so this is not a problem.

The meta-logical connectives should (and usually can) only be used on the ‘outermost level’ of a proposition.

Note however that when you *can* use the mega-logical ones, it is usually more convenient to use them because the object-level ones are opaque to Isabelle and the Isar proof language (i.e. they are functions just like any other function) whereas Isar ‘knows’ what `⟹` and `⋀` mean. For instance, if you have a fact stated with `⟹` and `⋀`, you can immediately instantiate variables and discharge assumptions in it using the `of`/`OF` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write it such that the value is not `prop` in the first place — there's no conversion. In this case, you used the prop-level implication `⟹` between `∀x. x ∈ A` and `(x, x) ∈ R`. You may use a single-width arrow `-->` instead, which is an implication of bools.